# Write $\mathbb{P}^X(A)$ as $\mathbb{E}[1_A X]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, expected-value

- $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ probability space
- $(E, \mathcal{B}(E))$ a measurable space where $B(E)$ is the Borel sigma algebra and $E$ is a Banach space
- $X:\Omega\to E$ random variable with distribution $\mathbb{P}^X$ on $(E, \mathcal{B}(E))$

I know that one can write the probability of an event as the expectation of an indicator function
$$
\mathbb{E}[1_A] = \int_{\Omega} 1_A(\omega) \mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \int_A d\mathbb{P} = \mathbb{P}(A).
$$

> Can I also write $\mathbb{P}^X(A) = \mathbb{E}[1_A X]$ for $A\in\mathcal{B}(E)$?

---

I have tried directly
$$
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{P}^X(A)
    &= \int_A \mathbb{P}^X(de) \\
    &= \int_E 1_A(e) \mathbb{P}^X(de)
\end{align}
$$
but I can't use the change of variables formula here, even if it is very suspitious. The random variable takes inputs in $\Omega$ not in $E$, I would be tempted to write
$$
\int_\Omega 1_A(X(\omega)) \mathbb{P}(d\omega)
$$

Comment: No, you can not.

Comment: @Kroki My question was born out of studying conditional expectations. It seems that a conditional expectation can be defined as the Radon-Nikodym derivative of the distribution of X https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Existence

Comment: This is false, obviously the left hand side is less than $1$ but the right hand side could very well be bigger than $1$. Recall that $\mathbb P^X(A) = \mathbb P(X \in A)$ be definition, so the right hand side should be $\mathbb E[1_{\{X \in A\}}]$.

Comment: I don't see much value in defining a $P^X$ function, rather than just writing $P[X \in A]$. The $P^X$ function just provides more opportunities for confusion.

Comment: @Michael I'm not convinced. $\mathbb{P}^X$ is a probability measure (a distribution) and it is well-defined. The notation $\mathbb{P}(X\in A)$ is only well-defined because there are some conventions. E.g. we have defined
$$
\{X \in A\} := \left\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\, X(\omega\in A\right\} = X^{-1}(A)
$$
and then we have chosen to write $\mathbb{P}(\{X\in A\}) = \mathbb{P}(X\in A)$. All of this holds because
$$
1_A\circ X(\omega) = \begin{cases}
    1 & X(\omega)\in A \\
    0 & X(\omega)\notin A
\end{cases}
$$
so really the integral can be split into two integrals, one going to zero.

Comment: What I mean at the end of my comment is that we can write
$$
\mathbb{P}^X(A) = \int_{X^{-1}(A)} 1\,\mathbb{P}(d\omega) + \int_{\Omega \backslash X^{-1}(A)} 0 \,\mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \int_{X^{-1}(A)} \mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \mathbb{P}(X^{-1}(A)) = \mathbb{P}(X\in A)
$$

Comment: Indeed I am using the convention $P[X \in A] = P[\{X \in A\}]$. I would assume the simplest definition would be $P^X(A) := P[X \in A]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(E)$, and there is no need for any integrals here (you have already assumed $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ is a prob space and $X:\Omega\rightarrow E$ a random element). If you want to do the reverse, by starting with a known distribution $\mu:\mathcal{B}(E)\rightarrow [0,1]$, then it is not obvious how to create a random element $X:\Omega\rightarrow E$ that has this distribution (and in fact it is not always possible to do so).

Comment: If you really dislike the notation $P[X\in A]$ you could simply define $P^X(A):=P[X^{-1}(A)]$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}(E)$, using the concept of the inverse image of a set through a function, though many students tend to think that the equivalent notation $P[X \in A]$ is less scary-looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathbb P^X \left[A\right] = \mathbb P\left[X\in A\right] = \mathbb E\left[\mathbf 1_{X\in A}\right]$$

The $A$ is Borel and $\left\{X\in A\right\} \in \mathcal B(E)$

Comment: How did you by-pass the problem with the change of variables formula?

Comment: I did not do any change of variable this is the definition of $\mathbb P^X$

Comment: Okay then maybe I need a new definition. The one I am working with is the pushforward
$$
\mathbb{P}^X = \mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}
$$

Comment: It is the same definition